# JavaScript in Apex: Popup Window to Perform Procedure Once Popup Window Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, triggers, oracle-apex, procedure

I am developing a resource scheduler using Oracle ApEx, in which users can reserve resources. If a resource is already reserved, a user has the option to either put the resource on hold or cancel the reservation. Currently. I am using a trigger to check the resource's status and update accordingly.

Here is what I want to know:

Once the "Reserve" button is clicked, if the resource is already reserved, I would like to call a pop up window using Javascript from the button, which will ask the user whether they would like to put the resource on hold. By clicking "Yes" on the pop up window, the system will then proceed to put the resource on hold for the user.

How can this be done?

Comment: What version of APEX?  And I don't understand what you mean by "I am using a trigger to check the resource's status and update accordingly". Do you mean a database trigger?  If so is it relevant to the question, since the checking must take place before any update is performed?

Comment: @TonyAndrews I am using Apex 4.0.2.00.09. Yes, I am using a trigger. It would be relevant in this case, as I would like to call the pop up window only when the status is set to "reserved".